# what is the meaning of lauren fox according to Peter Scholze?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education

Today I watched [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYZ3reRcVi8&t=2016s) interview of Field medalist [Peter_Scholze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Scholze). I have some confusion about a statement given by Peter Scholze  (video timing: $5:08$ to $5:11$). Here is the outline of the statement in the video:

> do something beautiful theory and so there i mean lauren fox somehow
> i learned from norman fox that there

what is the meaning of norman fox ?

Comment: Doesn’t sound to me like he says “Lauren Fox” but “Norman Fox” twice, in which case it is likely a name. There is a Norman Fox at Austin Peay State University. Not sure if that is to whom he is referring.

Comment: It could be another last name, like Fochs, but I’m not finding anything under that name.

Comment: He also talks about fock modules I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misheard and he's talking about **Laurent Fargues** there, from whom he learned something. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Fargues